# Golang function DigitalOcean private repo or vendor folder

Tags: go, digital-ocean, serverless

from what I can see on the digitalocean site for Go functions, it requires go 1.17, and has to be built on their systems. (no local build and push option).

trying to find an example or walkthrough on how to either allow the function build service access to a private repo or pass in vendor folder from go mod.

`doctl -v serverless deploy .` is the call being used, which works until I add a private repo of course.